# can't mount internal hdd in ubuntu 8.10

Tags: mount

$LogFile indicates unclean shutdown (0,0) Failed to mount'/dev/sda1':Operation not supported Mount is denied becouse NTFS is marked to be in use.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to a [supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

> Mount is denied becouse NTFS is marked to be in use.

This should be the full notice and it also includes what you should do:

> Mount is denied because NTFS is marked to be in use. Choose one action:
>
> Choice 1: If you have Windows then disconnect the external devices by
>    clicking on the 'Safely Remove Hardware' icon in the Windows
>    taskbar then shutdown Windows cleanly.
>
> Choice 2: If you don't have Windows then you can use the 'force' option for
>    your own responsibility. For example type on the command line:

```
  mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/{directory} -o force
```

where {directory} is the directory where it should have mounted.

> Regarding using Ubuntu 8.10

Please install a newer version of Ubuntu. 8.10 is no longer supported and Ubuntu has had some serious security updates.